# How can i create github repository for snipmatch (eclipse plugin)

Tags: eclipse

i created a repository for snipmatch from github.

eclipse gaves me an error like format-5 below

[image: format 5 error]

this is [the guide in the error](https://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/manual/#snippet-repository-update-guide)

i configured repository below.

i m new to git. i havent entered a password for github in eclipse , also ssh key. i dont know where can i enter these information.

[image: repository setting]

Comment: Have you followed the [repository creation guide](https://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/manual/#snippet-repository-creation-guide) in the URL you've posted? What part of it did give you problems?